# Link to custom archive page links to page-template instead

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

On my page-projects.php template page I am outputting image posts from my CPT 'projects'. 
I want to add a 'see all' link to my 'archive-projects.php (using: echo get_post_type_archive_link('/projects');), but it's linking to the same page-projects.php that I am on...

- created template page in root called page-projects.php
- in dashboard the page is 'photography' with slug of 'projects' and is assigned project template(page-projects.php) from 'page attributes' meta-box
- CPT is 'projects', and each project is assigned project template(page-projects.php) from 'page attributes' meta-box
- created archive-projects.php in root and in CPT code I have added for archive 'has_archive' => true

Why is it linking to my custom post type page that I am already on and not my custom post type archive page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page who list `projects` slug is `projects` AND your archive slug is also `projects` WordPress will always display your page.

The archive page need to have a different slug.

Comment: right. so if I changed my page to page-project.php with slug as project and change my archive to archive-projects.php, then it should be displaying my page template instead of my archive, would that be better?